# flashing Jetson TX2 ,by NVIDIA SDK Manager, with install error

Tags: nvidia, package-management, virtualbox, ubuntu-sdk

planning to use `virtualbox of ubuntu 18.04` and `SDK Manager` in order to **flashing Jetson TX2**

demo pic https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjyy7.jpg

**problem: the SDK package download failed with Dependency error**

- error shows

> apt-get missing dependencies, there are missing dependencies in
> apt-get database.Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages [ or
> specify a  solution ] in a terminal, and click RETRY.

I have tried this for about 3 days, still stock on this, I just want to flash TX2 ( ´•̥̥̥ω•̥̥̥` )

---

tried 2:
after I tried the error message suggest now the error looks like in below pic link
(error pic) https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIj2F.jpg

- error message

> 15:21:16 ERROR: CUDA on Host - host: command terminated with error
> 15:21:16 SUMMARY: VPI on Host - host: Depends on failed component
> ...
> ...   (normal message skipped)...
> ...
> 15:21:23 INFO: File System and OS - target_image: Depends: python2.7
> (>= 2.7.15~rc1-1~) but it is not going to be installed
> 15:21:23 ERROR:
> File System and OS - target_image: E: Unable to correct problems, you
> have held broken packages.
> 15:21:23 INFO: File System and OS -
> target_image: [ Package PreInstall Finished with Error ]
> 15:21:23
> ERROR: File System and OS - target_image: command terminated with
> error
> 15:21:23 SUMMARY: Device Mode Host Setup in Flash - flash:
> Depends on failed component

**have anyone experience this? how to do next though?**

Comment: Have you tried what the error message suggests?

Comment: @ChanganAuto now lead to the error two , I write on post too